# setTimeout(() => ele.click()) and ele.click() will lead different animation! So, is this related to browser rendering or event loops or something？

Tags: javascript, animation, click, settimeout, getcomputedstyle

```
#box {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}

<button id="btn">click</button>
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
    const box = document.getElementById('box');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
      box.style.transform = 'translateX(1000px)';
      box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-in-out';

      getComputedStyle(box).transform;
      box.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
      
    });

    // method 1
    document.getElementById('btn').click();
    
    // method 2
    setTimeout(() => {
      btn.click();
    }, 1000)
    
</script>
```

**context:**

> Google: 版本 92.0.4515.107（正式版本） (x86_64)

> Firefox: 版本: 90.0.2 (64 位)

In above code, method 1 and method 2 will lead different animation in both browers。 why？
I'm not talking about 1s delays

**example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-tharp-ommki?file=/index.html
and then change code, take a look

**Results:**

[method1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK0yn.gif)

[method2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jrDE.gif)

Comment: Very likely the browser doesn't render the style changes until after the function has finished, so calling the click listener from inside the function doesn't necessarily see all the changes. setTimeout will run after the function has finished, so will see the rendered results which might give different results to the in–function call.

Comment: What does the Function refer to?

Comment: The function passed to *addEventListener* and triggered by `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code with method #1 will work if you wrap all the code into:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => { ... });
```

[About event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).

It works because code will work after css was parsed and applied to element.

Current code fires before this. It causes to "jumping" of the element.

Comment: Do you mean method#1 will work before css parsed? But, "box.style.transform = 'translateX(1000px)';" This line of code doesn't seem to execute.

Comment: Why isn't this box from 1000px to 500px, I think (getComputedStyle(box).transform;) that will make browser remember the last state.

Comment: @noe 
What behavior are you expecting to? 
Do you expect that it should move right to 1000px, and then, after this, move left to 500 px?

Comment: I just want to know the operation details of click in setTimeout? Why does it look like 1000px doesn't work?

Comment: @noe
I've played around with your demo. As I said, if we put code into the `'load'` event handler, we will get consistent behavior for both `method1` and `method2`. But it looks like `translateX(1000px)` does not work. I'm not sure, but I think it is because some browser optimization. We set some value to box.style.transform, but it applies later, so the last value we set will be applied. Also if we put another value for transform property, and do it inside timeouted for 1s function, both translations will work.

Comment: Yeah, it make me so carzy. `getComputedStyle(box).transform` should make brower repaint. But I don't know. If you move `box.style.transition` to the after of `getComputedStyle(box).transform` , you will find it change too.  Amazing... sigh.....